# How would I be able to make it so a youtube embed cannot be paused [HTML5]

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

[I am making a chrome NewTab Extension - Here is a download link if you want to be able to see the exact code](https://mega.nz/#!tboTDb7I!urEjlPIba9OjshCPNXm9MRqRbS_69lQZxZp9bZBdYEI)

I want to be able to change make it so that end users cannot pause the youtube embed on my main index.html

```
 <div class="vidbg"style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the controls from the embedded player.
Put a transparent cover div over the player to stop direct clicking or interaction.
If you still wish to interact with the player, have js links for the api for the desired actions.